# co-located vs. co-partitioned RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm quite newbie in Spark and I have 2 Question:

1. I have a large set of points and I made an RDD (called `partitionedData`) from them and partitioned it based on a custom partitioner so that each partition has at most a threshold number of points. Because I need to choose some Points as a **leader** in each partition and  **be sure that the corresponding leaders and points in each partition are in a *same node***, I `mapPartitions` the `partitionedData` and set the `preservesPartitioning` flag as `true`. Finally, the result of this RDD is my desired **leader RDD**. Here is my first question: I know that the leader RDD preserves it's parent RDD partitioning (**co-partitioned**), but I'm not sure if the the leaders in each partition will be placed in a ***same node*** as their parents Points (**co-located**)?
2. If the answer of the above question is **NO**, so how can I co-locate the partitions of a given RDD with another pre-partitioned RDD?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be co-located for you to be able to guarantee no shuffling all the co-partition has to be done within the same action.

If you would have intermediary actions the Integer index the custom partitioner creates could be assigned to different nodes and in this case shuffle would be required.

Comment: It is simply put: do not lose the partitioner by means of transformations that hold and propagate the partitioner such as mapValues instead of map in which the key could be altered and apart from not losing the partitioner, take no action, in the moment there is one action you have no guarantee that the data will be in the same node.

Comment: -Could you please elaborate using some examples ?Thanks